# How to reset Windows 10 to the default DPK (the one installed in BIOS) on HP laptop?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, windows-activation, oem, hp-laptop

Some time ago I have activated my Windows Education licence key on the HP laptop to extend my Windows 10 capabilities.

Right now I would like to sell the laptop to some new user, so I have reset the Windows installation to the factory state. 
But obviously, my key remains activated in Windows.

I was wondering if it is safe to use `slmgr.vbs /upk` to get rid of my product key and then reset the Windows system to the factory state.

Do you possibly know is it going to proceed with OA3 (OEM Activation 3.0) during such Windows reset and activate my factory-state Windows product key?

I've done my homework, so I know, that:

> OEM Activation 3.0 (OA3) takes place at the factory. A digital product key (DPK) is installed on the motherboard BIOS during the manufacturing process.

and how to use the `slmgr` application. The thing is that I don't know how to force the activation of in-bios DPK, as I want to sell my laptop in vanilla state, with the stock, OEM Windows version and product key.

Comment: “I want to sell my laptop in vanilla state, with the stock, OEM Windows version and product key.“ - All you have to do is install the appropriate version of Windows that came with your machine.  Windows will automatically activate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 uses
[Digital entitlement](https://www.onmsft.com/news/digital-entitlement-a-new-method-of-activation-in-windows-10)
and activates based on the hardware configuration, and especially on the
OEM key.

There is no way for you to erase the OEM key, nor do you need to.
Any Windows 10 version that you install will pick it up automatically.

Reset was the right action to take, as it ensures that the installed Windows
version fits the OEM key (Home, Pro etc,).

You don't need to do any more than that.

---

If the Microsoft license servers are now fixed on the Digital Entitlement
of the Education serial and will pick it up automatically on reboot,
then you might try going into
*Settings > Update & Security > Activation*
and use the button "Change product key" to manually enter the OEM key.
This key should have been furnished you either as a sticker on the computer
itself or via a paper document.

If this doesn't work, then you need to call Microsoft Support and explain
the problem, asking them to delete the Education key from your entitlement.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, actually, it still remains "Education" as Windows version, this is why I wonder if I should unregister my own Education key (and if after that, the OEM key from Digital Entitlement would replace my key in some automatic way).

Comment: I added a second part to my answer.

Comment: Thanks :) And here is the hardest part - I do not have the serial in any form, not as a sticker, nor on a paper document. It is only persisted in BIOS. I will try to remove my key. If it fails, I will simply put it again... Or I will have to buy the box Home licence of Windows in order to sell this laptop, duh... :/

Comment: The OEM key is still there, so it's just a matter of using the right software. See [this article](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/find-windows-product-key) and [this product](https://neosmart.net/OemKey/), but there are more.

Comment: Great! Thanks :)  I will verify this solution and mark it

Answer (score 0):

In the end of the day it turned out, that the only solution was to simply reinstall whole laptop from a pendrive.
Education license is a kind of "Enterprise" variant of Windows. In result the soft "downgrade" solutions like this [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTjLd57QgDY) didn't work. 
After the complete reinstallation, Windows grabbed OEM key as-it-is, and activated automatically.

Thank you @harrymc for all the advices ;)